# Instructor's manual -- model answers from it by instructor

Tags: plagiarism, cheating

For a textbook, there is an instructor's manual provided by the publisher to the instructor that has prescribed the textbook in a course. The instructor sets some questions from the textbook as assignment. After the assignment is due, the instructor takes the solutions from the instructor's manual verbatim for the questions on the assignment and shares with the students as model solutions without stating that they are from the instructor's manual that he has access to. In this particular case, it seems clear that if students also have access to the instructor's manual (via free document repositories) and turn in answers verbatim from the instructor's manual, that would count as academic indiscipline. But what of the instructor's actions?

Another variation of this is the following. The students at the beginning of the course, ask for some model questions with answers to help them prepare. The instructor chooses questions and answers from a different textbook (for which he has the instructor's manual) than the one prescribed for the course. He shares with them at the beginning of the course these questions with solutions without citing the source.

If the source is cited by the instructor, and the students ask for access to the instructor's manual, on what basis can access to it be denied? At present, it seems that the only basis for such denial is an agreement with the publisher that the instructor will not share the complete instructor's manual.

What is the consensus view on these issues?

Comment: The view is that students should learn, so copying answers doesn't help them. The instructor is not there to learn.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in both cases, the instructor is just fine taking answers verbatim from the IM without saying so, creating a new document and sharing it with students.

Comment: @user111388 'The instructor is not there to learn.'  It ain't necessarily so.  On a couple of occasions, I've volunteered to TA on a course primarily because I wanted an excuse to schedule some time to learn the content of that course.

Comment: I don't.know what you mean by fine and if you are asking from a law perspective if the instructor can prevent cheating or if they teaxh well or something. But of course, tge students goal is to learn, so they should not look at the questions before. If the questions are good, it doesn't matter where they come from (at least feom an educational perspective).

Comment: @DanielHatton: What I mean is that it is not the course goal. Similar to industry - you may learn something while working, but this is not the company's goal of your employment.

Comment: What I meant was, is it plagiarism for the instructor to provide a verbatim copy of the IM's answers to students as model answers without citing its source.

Comment: @Tryer: Then remove the case about the students, its irrelevant. I'd say in an exam its okay, otherwise blindly copying is not okay for.an instrcutor when the source is hidden. But on this site, many people told me it is okay when a prof copies blindly teaching material and hides the source, because in teaching nobody expects new material, so there cannot be a plagiarism.

Comment: How is that not relevant? If student do it, we are all agreed that it is plagiarism. The question is, is it plagiarism if the instructor does so. You don't seem to be taking any stance on this issue. You say that "this site" says professors cannot plagiarize while teaching.

Comment: You asked for a consensus, I told you that this site's concensus (by a recent question ) seems to be that an instructor may copy, hide the source and this is okay (and for some reason may be better than copying and stating the source). My stance is that this is not okay for normal teaching, here the prof may copy, but should not hide the source imo (especially in public lectures), but in exams it's ok. And I think we all agree it's beyond unacceptable if students copy answers.

Comment: Ok, could you please share a link of that question with me?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159072/is-this-tenured-professor-plagiarizing-his-lectures/159237?noredirect=1#comment426111_159237

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you want to teach your students good academic practice in general as well as your specific subject, then you should let them know the source of the answers you provide, at least in general. "This comes from the book's authors" is probably enough. Otherwise they might get the idea that copying and plagiarism is fine. And if you represent the answers as your own work, then, yes, it is a form of plagiarism..

However, providing the answers verbatim, raises also the issue of over-copying from published material. It may be, however, that the instructor's guide provides specific guidance for use, possibly granting (or forbidding) such release. For some books, the questions/exercises are the most valuable part, and releasing this information can definitely lessen the value of the book, especially if students are likely to put such things online or otherwise cache them for others. That would be a copyright problem, but not a plagiarism issue if you give the source.

Third, while not an ethical issue, courtesy and respect for the authors might imply that you not give out answers verbatim, to protect the investment they made in producing it. And also courtesy and respect for future instructors (and students) who want to use the book in a way that maximizes learning and lessens the likelihood of student cheating.

Finally, there is the issue of serving your students. This can raise many issues, but, in general, *hints* for producing solutions are more valuable to their learning than just providing answers. In fact, minimal hints, that help them develop insight, are more valuable than extensive hints. There is a vast difference between developing an answer on your own and reading a solution. Developing a solution with minimal hints is very much closer to the former than the latter. This will aid their education rather than giving them the false impression that they have developed some skill or insight when they have not. Hints are also sometimes necessary to dispel misconceptions. Unfortunately, tailored hints don't scale very well.

To answer one of your concerns directly, you can deny them access on the basis that having those answers would inhibit their learning and that they should try a bit harder to work out the answers themselves.

So, my suggestion, as an experienced educator, is that you don't give these out for a variety of reasons, the most important one is the value that actually doing the exercises has for your students. Even if they struggle. Perhaps *especially* if they struggle. The purpose of education isn't "answers", but learning.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer in detail. However, it is unclear to me what the specific answers are to my specific questions in the OP. Reading between the lines of your paragraph beginning "Third, while not an ethical issue, ", I suppose that you would say that while not optimal, it is not plagiarism or academic-indiscipline if the instructor reproduces verbatim answers from the IM. Am I right or am I misstating your position?

Comment: Courtesy and respect are a bit different from plagiarism and copyright violation. It is an orthogonal issue. I don't imply that it isn't plagiarism. "It" refers to courtesy and respect, not to copying verbatim.

Comment: 'It may be, however, that the instructor's guide provides specific guidance for use, possibly granting (or forbidding) such release.'  Here in the UK, if any such guidance were stricter than the default position in public law, I think the guidance would be rendered void by section 32(3) of the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988 (but IANAL).